# Errors building and installing clBLAS on Ubuntu 16.04 (64bit)

Tags: ubuntu, cmake

I'm tring to build [clBLAS](https://github.com/clMathLibraries/clBLAS) from source on Ubuntu 16.04 (64bit).  From the `cmake` configuration output it appear the dependencies have been satisfied.  I'm being guided by instructions from [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jarutis/ff28bca8cfb9ce0c8b1a/raw/6c4954f6f20b9d22e262dde48acded18795d54bf/ubuntu.sh) like so;

```
## clBlas     
sudo apt-get install git     
git clone https://github.com/clMathLibraries/clBLAS.git     
cd clBLAS/      
mkdir build      
cd build/      
sudo apt-cache search openblas     
sudo apt-get install libopenblas-base libopenblas-dev      
sudo apt-get install liblapack3 liblapack-doc liblapack-dev      
cmake ../src      
make      
sudo make install 

make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/opt/AMDAPPSDK-
3.0/lib/x86_64/libOpenCL.so', needed by 'library/libclBLAS.so.2.10.0'. Stop.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:223: recipe for target 'library/CMakeFiles/clBLAS.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [library/CMakeFiles/clBLAS.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:149: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I haven't included all the output, just the final few lines showing the issue when `sudo make install` is run.  Can anyone suggest what the trouble is here and how to get clBLAS to build? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Catalyst fglrx was discontinued for ubuntu 16.04. It only uses the free version software amdgpu. I had to move back to 14.04 to use the driver properly, because my graphics card is a R7 M200, and it is not fully supported by amdgpu.

You can find more information [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD) and in a separate question on Ask Ubuntu [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/744057) ("I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and there's no fglrx!").

Answer (score 0):

One of the requirements noted on the [build page](https://github.com/clMathLibraries/clBLAS/wiki/Build-clBLAS-library-*.a-or-*.so-files-only#user-content-build-dependencies) is the AMD APP SDK, which has been deprecated - see [here](https://community.amd.com/thread/228059#comment-2866963). You may need that installed to get it to work, however note it is deprecated.

Although I have not worked with anything related to this (clBLAS), a quick search comes up with [CLBlast](https://github.com/CNugteren/CLBlast), which might be suitable for your needs. It also seems to still be getting updates.